# Error (mysql) during software update ubuntu 16

Tags: updates, ubuntu-16.04

I have over 100 packets to update. When I start updating and then I get an error

```
mysql-common
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

So, I try to uninstall mysql-common

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-common
```

Sadly I get a results

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have        
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable       
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created       
or been moved out of Incoming.                                           
The following information may help to resolve the situation:             

The following packages have unmet dependencies:                          
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried to remove mysql-client-5.7

```
[...]
Unpacking mariadb-client (10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: mysql-client-5.7: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 dbconfig-mysql depends on mysql-client | mariadb-client | virtual-mysql-client; however:
  Package mysql-client is not installed.
  Package mariadb-client is not configured yet.
  Package virtual-mysql-client is not installed.
  Package mysql-client-5.7 which provides virtual-mysql-client is to be removed.
[...]
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-common:
 mariadb-common depends on mysql-common (>= 5.6.25); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libreadline5:amd64 (5.2+dfsg-3build1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-client-core-10.0:
 mariadb-client-core-10.0 depends on mariadb-common (>= 10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-client-core-10.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-client-10.0:
 mariadb-client-10.0 depends on mariadb-client-core-10.0 (>= 10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-client-core-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-client-10.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-client:
 mariadb-client depends on mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-client-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   Setting up libappindicator1 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libappindicator3-1 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 mariadb-common
 mariadb-client-core-10.0
 mariadb-client-10.0
 mariadb-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to remove mariadb* I still get an errors.

Any idea, how can I resolve my problem and update my OS?